# Miracast sink for linux that integrates seamlessy with the environment

Tags: linux

I'm looking for a solution that allows me to project my mobile's screen onto a **window**, optionally full-screen, and give keyboard and mouse input back to the phone. My phone supports desktop mode while projecting, which I am trying to put to good use.

I have tried [Miraclecast](https://github.com/albfan/miraclecast), but

1. It requires me to dedicate the network entirely to the cast
2. Buffers the input so much that it becomes unusable for an interactive session
3. Couldn't get the UIBC protocol to work, so the phone doesn't get any input back

I am not sure anything can be done about (1) (even though "Miracast over infrastructure" seems to solve that problem, but do Android devices support it?), but the other two points really bother me a lot.

I am looking for a seamless, out of the box solution. If it doesn't exist, which is the one that comes closest that I could help debug/fix?